# kd-tree optimality for orthogonal range search

Tags: ds.algorithms, ds.data-structures, computational-geometry, high-dimensional-geometry

It is known that a kd-tree can be constructed for $n$ points ($k$-dimensional) in $O(n \log n)$ time and searching of any axis-aligned hyperrectangle can be done in time $O(n^{1-1/k} + out)$ time where $out$ is the number of points in the hyperrectangle. Is this optimal, i.e., is it known that there cannot be a data structure that can be built in $O(n \log n)$ time and allows orthogonal range search in $O(n^{1-1/k - \epsilon} + out)$ time for any constant $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: I believe it can be done in $O(\log^k(n)+out)$

Comment: Yes, using range trees, but range trees cannot be constructed in $O(n \log n)$ time. My question is specifically for only $O(n \log n)$ time allowed.

Comment: For $k=2$, this is definitely false. Range trees with fractional cascading can build the tree in $O(n \log n)$ and answer the query in $O(\log n)$